# Disable a Module in Certain Theme

Tags: magento, module, themes

Is it possible to disable certain modules when running a certain theme?  I'm working on a mobile friendly version of our Magento store and I've run into some issues with a few extensions.  Rather than customize them, the default iphone theme is sufficient, so I'd like to just disable those modules so it runs the default code when on a mobile device.  Is this possible?  If not, perhaps I'm approaching this from the wrong angle.  What is the right way to handle this type of thing?

Comment: What sort of code? A block or Javascript file perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to look into the Exceptions portion of the System configuration, you should be able to at least setup some conditions for mobile user agents.

An Article I wrote a while back on using the iphone theme for android may help shed some light for you:

http://www.molotovbliss.com/iphone-magento-theme-compatible-with-android

As far as disabling modules based of the exceptions sounds like you'll need to manage the modules etc/ xml files to set `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>` when needed, however I believe you could disable the output of the module via a built in method also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @B00MER.  Unfortunately, you haven't given me any new information.  I already have the exception configured to load the iphone theme for mobile devices.  What I need is a way to _programatically_ disable a module for the iphone theme.  As I understand it, setting a module's active to true or false is global.  So how to do I turn it off only for one theme or another?

Comment: Sorry couldn't be of more help.  You may want to look at this code to give you some insight on how to read and write a modules xml file to allow for setting `<active>` node appropriately.  https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug/blob/master/code/Debug/controllers/IndexController.php specifically the `toggleModuleStatusAction()` method, NOTE: However the more that I think about it, this will disable the module on the other regular browsing side as well.

Comment: You can also try this instead of modifying the xml file: `Mage::getConfig()->setNode('advanced/modules_disable_output/Namespace_Module', false);` Reference: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-programmatically-change-magentos-core-config-data/

Answer (score 0):

Brian, I think you can do it using local.xml file that is template dependent.
Here are some examples from my file:

```
<default>
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="left.newsletter" />
</reference>
</default>
```

When you use the remove tag, it removes any blocks with the specified name from
the entire layout, regardless of the context. So, if I remove right.newsletter in
the  context and that name is used in say the  context,
then both blocks will be removed.  Because remove operates on the global context,
you can only remove an element once.